# All two-storey commercial properties with a certain building number situated on a junction in Overpass Turbo

Tags: overpass-api

I'm trying to find two-storey commercial buildings whose number is 46, situated on a corner. The properties are unlikely to have ever been residential and are probably still commercial although I don't know specifically what, i.e. shop, cafe etc.

So far I have:

```
[out:xml][timeout:25];
(
    node["addr:housenumber"="46"]["building:levels"="2"][building=retail]({{bbox}});
    way["addr:housenumber"="46"]["building:levels"="2"][building=retail]({{bbox}});
    relation["addr:housenumber"="46"]["building:levels"="2"][building=retail]({{bbox}});  
);
out meta;
>;
out meta qt;
```

This returns results however how do I specify any type of commercial use as opposed to just retail, and how do I specify it should be on a corner\junction ?

Comment: _situated on a junction in Overpass Turbo_ is a concept that is very difficult to model with Overpass API. I don't expect that this could be done in a query.